# How do I update content in the parent window of the Iframe I am in with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I am inside the contents of iframe_2 how do I change the text of header_2?

```
<h3 id="header_1"></h3>
<iframe id="iframe_1"></iframe>
<h3 id="header_2"></h3>
<iframe id="iframe_2"></iframe>
<h3 id="header_3"></h3>
<iframe id="iframe_3"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out.

```
$("h3#header2", parent.document).text("new text");
```